# Display option and empty value

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, x-editable

I need some help with the display option of x-editable. This is needed to display short text of a textarea.

```
display: function(value) {
        if (value) {
            value = value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");
            if (value.length > 20) {
                value = value.substr(0, 17) + '...';
            }
            $(this).html(value);
        }
    }
```

This works fine if there is database content. Without content there will be no output and no link to write new content.
So, how do I display this link to the "default input's display" if there is no content?

It is working now with **else** and **$(this).empty();**

```
display: function(value) {
        if (value) {
            value = value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");
            if (value.length > 20) {
                value = value.substr(0, 17) + '...';
            }
            $(this).html(value);
        } else {
            $(this).empty();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#newrecord) will help you.